# Some images are displayed and some not on React Native Android

Tags: react-native

I have one strange problem.

I'm creating an React Native app and I have problem with images loading.

On IOS works everything perfect, but I have problems on Android.

On Android only some of the images are loaded the rest of the images aren't shown. I do not get any errors in console, it seems that everything works fine, but the images are not showing.

[image]

The images are in one component :

```
const items = [
    { image: require('./front-left.png'), file: frontLeft, item: 'front-left' },
    { image: require('./left.png'), file: left, item: 'left' },
    { image: require('./rear-left.png'), file: rearLeft, item: 'rear-left' },
    { image: require('./rear.png'), file: rear, item: 'rear' },
    { image: require('./rear-right.png'), file: rearRight, item: 'rear-right' },
    { image: require('./right.png'), file: right, item: 'right' },
    { image: require('./front-right.png'), file: frontRight, item: 'front-right' },
    { image: require('./top.png'), file: top, item: 'top' },
    { image: require('../common/front.png'), file: front, item: 'front' },
    { image: require('../common/inside.png'), file: inside, item: 'inside' },
    { image: require('../common/parts1.png'), file: parts1, item: 'parts1' },
    { image: require('../common/parts2.png'), file: parts2, item: 'parts2' },
    { image: require('../common/parts3.png'), file: parts3, item: 'parts3' },
    { image: require('../common/parts4.png'), file: parts4, item: 'parts4' },
    { image: require('../common/inside-dashboard.png'), file: insideDashboard, item: 'inside-dashboard' },
];
```

And then I use them as follows:

```
import * as Picture from '../../img/picture/berline/index';
const items = Picture.items;

..........

<Image contain='contain' source={items[this.props.index].image} style={{width: width/5 - 4, height: width/8 - 4, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
    {this.noDamageIcon()}
    {this.damageIcon()}
</Image>


..........
```

It tried to create `apk` and install it on my device, but I have the same problem.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: This is possibly a heap issue - inside of `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` try adding `android:largeHeap="true"` under `application`.

Comment: @G0dsquad I just tried it, but the issue is still the same.

Comment: Any difference between device and emulator?

Comment: @G0dsquad No, the same problem on both. It's very strange.

Comment: Any difference in the naming or properties of the images from `rear-right` onwards e.g @2x, @3x equivalents not specified for Android? This is very odd!

Comment: @G0dsquad No, there is no difference.

Comment: do you get any error messages in android studio console or command prompt?

Comment: @divine No, I do not see any errors.

Comment: source={{uri:imageURI}} - the source attribute of yours does not have missing braces , right?

Comment: @divine `require` is used as `source={require('./img/favicon.png')}`

Comment: could you try using this format? -- source={{uri: 'yourimage.png'}}

Comment: @divine That wouldn't change much, because some of the images are displayed, thus there is something else what causing the issue.

Comment: @Boky did you come to a solution for this ... I am getting the same thing except with external url links. Just curious if your solution would happen to fix mine?

Comment: @Taylor King I've added largeHeap:true and updated React Native to 0.48 and that did the trick.

Comment: @Boky ah, thanks so much! I actually just added the largeHeap:true thing as well, and it did work. I was hesitant at first because it didn't seem to work for you the first time ... but I'm glad it has been fixed. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I've had the same problem in debug mode, but as soon as I came into release mode, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either one of this solution:

`Image: resizeMethod="resize"`
or
`FlatList: removeClippedSubviews={true}`